# Auth0 and Vue 3, route to different view AFTER log in, depending on what role user has

Tags: vue.js, auth0

Im using auth0 for my application, where im trying to, depending on what role the logged in user have, route to a view, instead of having it on one view.
So lets say i have roles X,Y and Z. If my user logs in with the role X, i want to be redirected to "/Xhome", and same for the other roles. Is it possible to do it like this? Since im not verifying anything for the moment, or sending a token. I just want a check for some what:

```
if(auth.user.role === "x"){
 //route to "/XHome"
}
```

Cuz of right now, it just redirects to the "normal" page, as "/".

So basicly the flow i want is

```
Login anywhere => Auth0 login page => enter credentials => do a check for roles => redirect to that role homepage
```

and right now my useAuth file looks like this.

```
//UseAuth0.js

export const AuthState = reactive({
    user: null,
    loading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    auth0: null,
    token: '',
})

const config = {
    domain: 'mydomain',
    client_id: 'myclientId',
   
}

export const useAuth0 = state => {
    const handleStateChange = async () => {
        state.isAuthenticated = !!(await state.auth0.isAuthenticated())
        state.user = await state.auth0.getUser()
        state.loading = false
        state.token = await state.auth0.getTokenSilently()
    }

    const initAuth = () => {
        state.loading = true
        createAuth0Client({
            domain: config.domain,
            client_id: config.client_id,
            audience: config.audience,
            cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        }).then(async auth => {
            state.auth0 = auth
            await handleStateChange()
        })
    }
//Im guessing i should be able to do something here maybe?
    const login = async () => {
        await state.auth0.loginWithRedirect(),
        await handleStateChange()
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        state.auth0.logout({
            returnTo: window.location.origin,
        })
    }

    return {
        login,
        logout,
        initAuth,
    }
}
```

Is it possible to it like im trying to do here?
Or is this an issue I have to do in Auth0 it self?

Any advice helps, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loggin in the user, yo can check its role and redirect it to his corresponding home with a router.push("homeX") for example. And then in the router file, do something like this:

```
export const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { 
            path: '/', 
            component: HomePage, 
            meta: { authorize: [] } 
        },
        { 
            path: '/homeX', 
            component: HomeX, 
            meta: { authorize: [Role.X], role: "X" } 
        },
        { 
            path: '/homeY', 
            component: HomeY, 
            meta: { authorize: [Role.Y], role: "Y" } 
        },
        { 
            path: '/login', 
            component: LoginPage 
        },

        // otherwise redirect to home
        { path: '*', redirect: '/' }
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    const { authorize } = to.meta;
    const currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

    if (authorize) {
        if (!currentUser) {
            // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
            return next({ path: '/login', query: { returnUrl: to.path } });
        }

        // check if route is restricted by role
        if (authorize.length && currentUser.role !== to.meta.role) {
            // role not authorised so redirect to home page
            return next({ path: '/' });
        }
    }

    next();
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! One issue i have with this is that i dont have a /login page, infact i just call the login method from the useAuth.js, which redirects me to auth0 own login page. or would this work with ur example maybe?

Comment: so after calling the auth0 method, you check the auth.user.role and push the route depending on the route

Comment: in the router file or in the useAuth0? Im guessing it is in the router considering ur snippet

Comment: in useAuth0 or wherever in your Vue application you are calling the login function

Comment: managed to do a scuffed solution (imo) at the login page. on mounted checks which role the user has, if it has X role, router.push('/Xhome'). Will try to test this today

Comment: that sounds good!